# Prove that the piecewise function $f$ is integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I would like to prove that the following function is integrable $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{|x| (\log(|x|^{-1})^2} & |x| \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \mathrm{o.w.} \\ \end{cases}$$  i.e. I would like to show $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)| \, dx < \infty$. Unfortunately, I have no clue where to start. The exercise comes from Stein & Shakarchi's *Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces* text (pg. 146).

Unfortunately, with a messy function like this, I am not sure how to proceed. I could start with

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)| \, dx = \int_{|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}} |f(x)| \, dx + 0 = \int_{|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}} \Big| \frac{1}{|x| (\log(|x|^{-1})^2} \Big| \, dx$$

$$= \int_{|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}}  \frac{1}{|x| (\log(|x|^{-1})^2}  \, dx \leq \int_{|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{|x|} \, dx$$

But it feels wrong to omit the log function entirely like this. Any suggestions or hints on how to proceed would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You (and the answer incidentally) have mismatched parentheses in your denominator